# Max-height with Quill rich editor

Tags: css, quill

I try to set the `max-height:200px` CSS property to the Quill rich editor. I would like a scrollbar to appear when the entry is more than 200px.

As you can see on the following JSfiddle, it is not working properly:

https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/d8n5mjsq/7/

On GitHub, the Quill founder say it should work : https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/812

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: add `overflow: auto;` and voila.

Comment: T'es le meilleur! Merci. (You are the best! Thank you.)

Comment: No problem have a great weekend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` in your CSS, it will add the scrollbar.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me.

```
.ql-editor{
  height: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```